# SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Broker Troubleshooting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I set up Service Broker between two databases on separate instances, one on a 2008 R2 Cluster the other on a separate box also 2008 R2.  I have gone through the process of setting up all the objects (users, message types, contracts, queues, services, endpoints, routes, remote service bindings, and certificates), but I am getting 5 errors when I run ssbdiagnose.

ssbdiagnose -E -d MyDatabase CONFIGURATION FROM SERVICE /test/initiator TO SERVICE /test/target

http://jeffreylangdon.com/ssb.png  -- tried to post the error image, but apparently not an option since I am new to this forum.

Starting from the top error I have no idea why the Service Initiator can't be found considering I am running ssbdiagnose on the box where it resides.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jeff Langdon

@jlangdon

Answer (score 2):

The way you run `ssbdiagnose` in the post it would connect to the database `MyDatabase` on localhost and search for the `initiator` and `target` service. You mention that you've set up for two different instances, so the correct command line should be something like:

```
ssbdiagnose CONFIGURATION\
  FROM SERVICE /test/initiator -E -S <instance1> -d <db1>\
  TO SERVICE /test/target -E -S <instance2> -d <db2>
```

(I used the unix style command line terminators to prettify the code. You should use a single line).

When the connection params are pulled out ahead of the `CONFIGURATION` keyword they apply to every connection (FROM, TO).

Comment: Thanks for the ssbdiagnose syntax, that worked much better. Service Broker is now working between the two instance, mostly interested in sending messages from the Initiator to the Target.  I ran ssbdiagnose again and I am only getting one errror.  The target instance error is the "Contract DEFAULT is not bound to the Target service.  I can't seem to find much on Contract Defaults.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to specify the ON CONTRACT used to ssbdiagnose. Otherwise it assumes is the contract named DEFAULT